# Control the work for one Stream Multiprocessor in cuda

Tags: cuda

I am working with a cuda program which I managed to assign a work to one Stream Multiprocessor. For example, I have the works A and B and my GPU has 2 SMs (SM0 and SM1). Are there ways to assign the work A exactly to SM0 and the work B to SM1?

Can you suggest me some ways to do that?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Consider adding some code samples

Comment: you don't want to write programs that assign work to individual SMs.  Let the GPU do that.  This is a bad idea.  Create however much work you have, organize it into blocks, and let the blocks be handled by the GPU.  Today you are working on a GPU with 2 SMs.  Tomorrow it may be a GPU with 8 SMs.  The GPU will handle the scheduling for you.

Comment: Thanks M Afifi and Robert Crovella. But I wonder there are any ways to partition works to SMs manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to implement work A in (let's say) kernelA and work B in kernelB and launch both as a 1*1 grid in separate streams, because on Fermi and Kepler GPUs such kernels can run concurrently. The reason for the 1*1 grid launch is that if you have more than one blocks then those blocks may execute on different SMs and in that case the two kernels cannot execute at the same time (i.e. only one kernel/SM)

```
cudaStream_t stream1, stream2;
cudaStreamCreate ( &stream1 );
cudaStreamCreate ( &stream2 );
kernelA<<<1, 512, 0, stream1>>>(...);
kernelB<<<1, 512, 0, stream2>>>(...);
...
```

For more details, see [this NVIDIA presentation](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/StreamsAndConcurrencyWebinar.pdf)

Comment: Thanks Reguj. That is a good idea. Do you think it is feasible if with each stream we use it's own texture memory? For example, we create texture1 for stream1 and texture2 for stream2? I wonder which is faster between  using 1 texture for 2 streams and 2 texture for 2 streams.

Comment: Yes, that should work (though there is a limited number of texture slots)